# AchartEngine Pie Chart Orientation issue

Tags: android, orientation, achartengine, pie-chart

I am using AchartEngine Lib for displaying Pie chart inside my application, but I am facing a weird issue like when I changes the orientation of my phone the pie chart is not centred aligned it changes the direction anywhere.
Please let me know how can I centre aligne the pie Chart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem creating it inside a Fragment.

After spending hours and hours, I managed to do it by overriding **onConfigurationChanged** method.

The problem is that **onConfigurationChanged** is called before the layout change, and I couldn't find any method called after layout. Adding a sleep into it seems to do the trick.

You must remove the chartView from your layout, make it null, recreate it and then add again to the layout.

Code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch(Exception e) { }
            chartLayout.removeView(mChartView);
            mChartView = null;
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(getActivity(), mSeries, mRenderer);
            chartLayout.addView(mChartView);
        }
    });
}
```